# Is there any way to restrict list of pods to just pod names(not details) using kubernetes authorization webhook?

Tags: kubernetes

I am currently developing an authorization webhook to manage user access to various resources within Kubernetes. I am seeking a solution that will enable users to access only the names of pods within a namespace (list verb), without allowing access to the pod manifests or details (-o yaml) but allow users to view/change their 'owning' pods (get verb).

Is it possible to achieve this using the authorization webhook and SubjectAccessReview? (or is there another k8s-friendly solution)